# From iOS app on Simulator, launch OS X shell script

Tags: ios, macos, shell, ios-simulator, xctest

Is it possible from inside iOS app code to run Mac OS X shell script (or any other OS X program)?

The concrete situation is following: I'm playing with UI XCTests and want to run shell script in `setup()` and `tearDown()` methods of test cases. The purpose is to launch screen recording while the test is running.

Comment: I think guys from Apple took great efforts to make sure no one can launch anything on os x from simulator;) Don't know exactly how to solve your problem but I'd suggest you to look at XCode command line tools.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz, I hope Apple guys left some "backdoor" for such kind of things. Other way I imagine is possible - to interact with external environment via web-based interface. For example, VLC player does it. But this approach will be too complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, looks like nobody knows easy workarounds. So I solved it with local web-server on python.

Python has built-in `BaseHTTPServer` class. With this tutorial for example: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=1658 we can write simple web-server to handle POST request and performs some action.

In my case the action is to call bash script

```
os.system(someCommandString)
```

To launch all this mechanism we need to run python webserver. Then inside `XCTestCase` subclass in `setup()` and `tearDown()` methods we perform request to the server, ex:

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager().POST("http://0.0.0.0:8080/command", parameters: params, success: { (NSURLSessionDataTask, AnyObject) in
        print("succeed")
    }, failure: { (NSURLSessionDataTask, NSError) in
        print("failed")
    })
```